# Windows 10: different scaling when using external display vs laptop only

Tags: windows-10, scaling

Is there any software/trick that would set my laptop display scaling differently when external monitor is connected vs no external monitor?

When I go fully mobile I have the laptop screen close to face, so 100% scaling is fine. When using external monitor, I also use external kb/mouse, and laptop is further away, so that 125% scaling is better. Is there a way to switch this automatically?

Comment: Try using the settings for different monitors to see if this helps you.    https://www.howtogeek.com/304036/how-to-adjust-scaling-for-different-monitors-in-windows-10/

Comment: Not really, since it's the same monitor, just 2 different usecases.

Comment: If it is the same monitor, it will not switch automatically. The scaling is set for all applications on one screen.

Comment: I was hoping there's some app that'd do it :)

Comment: I have never seen an app that would do that. Screen settings override app requirements normally.

Comment: I was rather thinking along lines of using some Windows API to detect that monitor configuration changed and updating DPI based on that.